# Replacing string content with dropdown and continuing with text in span tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm reading text content from XML file using jQuery AJAX, now inside CDATA I have placed a text content like `Lorem ispum pre _BLANK_ Lorem ispum post` and I'm replacing the `_BLANK_` with a dropdown box using `indexOf` method.

What I want is the following:

```
<span class="label">Lorem ispum pre</span> 
<[My dropdown]> 
<span class="label">Lorem ispum post</span>
```

I mean I want to start and end span element dynamically before and after I replace the `_BLANK_` from the string with dropdown.

I hope i have at least satisfactorily explained the question. Please revert in case of any query. Thanks

eg. Node in xml

```
<ddLabel><![CDATA[17 _BLANK_ A Prime or Composite number.]]></ddLabel>
```

and following is my js code

```
ddActivitySelect = ddActivitySelect + "</select>";
if ($(this).find('ddLabel').text().indexOf('_BLANK_') === -1) {
    ddActivity = ddActivity + "<div class='sentence'>" + 
           $(this).find('ddLabel').text() +
           "</div>";
} else {
    ddActivity = ddActivity + "<div class='sentence'>" + 
           $(this).find('ddLabel').text().replace('_BLANK_', ddActivitySelect) +
           "</div>";
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Note that your `if` ... `else` construct isn't actually required - the same result is given on `replace` whether or not `_BLANK_` is in your string.

Comment: ok...thank you for that info. but how to add span pre and post replace